# Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression for socket.io and express

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm, webpack, laravel-mix

I installed Laravel and run `npm run watch` command, it returned:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/destroy/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\xampp\htdocs\checknpm\node_modules\destroy'

ERROR in ./node_modules/express/lib/request.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in 'C:\xampp\htdocs\checknpm\node_modules\express\lib'

ERROR in ./node_modules/engine.io/lib/server.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'uws' in 'C:\xampp\htdocs\checknpm\node_modules\engine.io\lib'
```

Then I set some configuration in laravel `webpack.mix.js`:

```
mix.webpackConfig({
    target: "node",
});
```

and it retuned:

```
WARNING in ./node_modules/socket.io/lib/index.js
113:11-32 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

WARNING in ./node_modules/node-gyp-build/index.js
13:9-32 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

WARNING in ./node_modules/node-gyp-build/index.js
20:15-54 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

WARNING in ./node_modules/express/lib/view.js
81:13-25 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

ERROR in ./node_modules/engine.io/lib/server.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'uws' in 'C:\xampp\htdocs\checknpm\node_modules\engine.io\lib'
```

and lastly I added:

```
mix.webpackConfig({
    target: "node",
    externals: {
        uws: "uws",
        ws: "ws",
    },
});
```

when I run `npm run watch` it returned:

```
WARNING in ./node_modules/socket.io/lib/index.js
113:11-32 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
 @ ./node_modules/socket.io/lib/index.js
 @ ./resources/js/bootstrap.js
 @ ./resources/js/app.js
 @ multi ./resources/js/app.js ./resources/sass/app.scss

WARNING in ./node_modules/express/lib/view.js
81:13-25 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
 @ ./node_modules/express/lib/view.js
 @ ./node_modules/express/lib/application.js
 @ ./node_modules/express/lib/express.js
 @ ./node_modules/express/index.js
 @ ./resources/js/bootstrap.js
 @ ./resources/js/app.js
 @ multi ./resources/js/app.js ./resources/sass/app.scss
```

I tried different ways but it didn't work! I want to have a socket relation with Laravel however it sends me these errors and it doesn't even let me to run socket. how can I fix it?

Comment: first run `npm install`

Comment: I had run that, but again I run it again as you said but  no result :(

Comment: As I can see these re warnings, there is no error in this

Comment: don't they make any problem during socket programming?

Answer (score 0):

just add this line in webpack.mix.js

```
        target: "node",
    externals: {
        express: 'express',

    },
```